# Change application name and icon programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-launcher

Is there any way that the user can choose the application name and launcher icon of my app and set it programmatically?

I want to give the permission to user so that he can rename my application and also change the launcher icon of the app.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you can do is to define multiple Launcher Activities with pre-defined icons and labels, and enable/disable them programmatically.

[setComponentEnabledSetting (ComponentName componentName, int newState, int flags)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#setComponentEnabledSetting(android.content.ComponentName,%20int,%20int))

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change either of these values easily.  You could create new Launcher Icons from inside the app, and then control them easier - like the other answer suggests).

Bottom line, this is not easily done using standard Android framework to the best of my knowledge.